# Efficent way for Flask using server side session Maintenance with uniquie key need to pass at every reqest

Tags: facebook, session, python-3.x, flask, server-side

Here it sounds weird but it is problem to me too.
I need to store server side session (mostly using db) using flask and python3.4.

In this case client will have an generated ***uniquey key*** (it is an app which will do it on client side)

It will login into the facebook/twitter/any.... oauth site based on token it will store it in db with ***uniquey key*** as primary key to db on server side .

client every time request data using the ***uniquey key*** .
and he will be able to retrieve the session data related ***uniquey key***.

eg:-
Here It will be Client get logged in using ***Firefox*** with ***uniquey key*** .
And able to Retrieve his info in ***Chrome*** using that  ***uniquey key*** with him.

how can i use flask and emulate this method.??

I was able to do this using http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/86/
but problem here it create new file for each session. and it will create heap of file on server. How i can avoid this *or* in **flask** can i create corn job and how??

*OR* any better alternative to this solution especially in **flask**.

u can also suggest me in (Django).

Comment: could use redis as session storage and have each client have a unique key under which all the other related session data can be found. Check out the server side session with redis here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/

Comment: Do you think it is efficient enough then _sqlite3_ http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/86/.